# How do I set the scaling of my lightdm to 1?

Tags: unity, login, lightdm

I am using a Surface Pro 3 with Ubuntu and I would like to apply the scaling of 1 to the lightdm login screen.

This is an image of my display settings with the scaling at one. This setting allows my desktop to have the correct size that I want, but this setting does not affect the login screen setting.

[image]

This is an image of my over-sized lightdm login screen. (I believe the scaling is set to 2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug in the unity-greeter, which is being worked on:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1571640

When you want to use the onscreen keyboard from the accessibility menu in the login screen:

- make sure it is turned off (reboot if necessary, because it's not visible)
- enable onscreen keyboard (then it's scaled correctly and visible)
- enter your password (but do not press enter)
- disable the onscreen keyboard in the accessibility menu again
- press the right arrow in the password field to login

I'm using my Surface Pro 3 (with the tigerite kernel) mainly without the type cover attached, and often use symless (synergy). So I have to login with the touchscreen until synergy is autostarted.